fcm sdk in chrome extension v3
I’m working on a Chrome Extension (v3) and need to implement push notifications using Firebase. I've already set up a project in the Firebase console for this purpose. However, I'm encountering an issue obtaining the registration token required to send push notifications from the console, despite using the Firebase SDK.
Below is my manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "FCM Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [ "notifications", "storage" ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
    //"type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "firebase-messaging-sw.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "48": "images/icon.png"
  }
}

and background.js as
importScripts('firebase/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('firebase/firebase-messaging-compat.js');


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*",
    authDomain: "*",
    projectId: "*",
    storageBucket: "*",
    messagingSenderId: "*",
    appId: "*",
    measurementId: "*"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

console.log('here');
// Retrieve Firebase Messaging object
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
console.log(messaging);

async function fetchToken() {
    try {
        const token = await getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: '*************' }); 
        console.log('FCM Token:', token);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting token:', error);
    }
}

fetchToken();


I tried installing firebase locally but couldn't refer functions
inside
I also tried using static firebase files but manifest loading failed due to bad imports and then after adding module type in service worker I got error that browser doesn't support it.
Also tried bundling background through webpack
Finally after loading firebase app and messaging js (version 9.0.0) compat version locally in a folder inside my chrome extension I was able to retrieve messaging object with the above mentioned code, but still getToken function wasn't working from messaging.js


Don't repost the same question multiple times please. At best they will be closed, but it may get you banned from the site. If you have clarifications on your original question, there's a small edit link under it to make such changes.
